# Return INT value from 'SELECT' stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Lets say we have 2 tables: `table1` with  fields `id(INT)`, `name(VARCHAR)` and `table2` with fields `id(A_I, INT)`, `id_from_t1(INT)`, `vc_for_t2(VARCHAR)`.

I have stored procedures:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_one`(IN `name_to_find` VARCHAR(45), IN `varchar_for_table2` VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SET @foundId = `function_two`(`name_to_find`);
    CALL `procedure_three`(`varchar_for_table2`, @foundId);
END$$

CREATE FUNCTION `function_two`(`name_to_find` VARCHAR(45))
RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE varResult INT(11);
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR(
        SELECT
            `t1`.`id`
        FROM table1 AS `t1`
        WHERE `t1`.`name` = `name_to_find`
        LIMIT 1);
    OPEN myCursor;
    FETCH myCursor INTO varResult;
    RETURN varResult;
END$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_three`(IN `varchar_for_table2` VARCHAR(45), IN `id_from_table1` INT(11))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `table2`(`vc_for_t2`, `id_from_t1`) 
        VALUES(`varchar_for_table2`, `id_from_table1`);
END$$
```

So problem is in function_two.
Now im using cursor but as I remember there was a faster way to fetch SELECT's result set, but i cant remember where have i seen it...

Comment: I think your query is right. and it should work. Have you tried it yet.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, no. As I understand now result of query is a table with one row and one column 'id'. But I need exact integer value, it is probably must look like (abstract code) `RETURN temp_table[1]['id']` and there should be  `INTO temp_table` after `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well in your second proc-

```
SELECT id = (SELECT `t1`.`id` 
             FROM table1 AS `t1` 
             WHERE `t1`.`name` = `name_to_find' 
             LIMIT 1;)
```

Comment: its still return a single row and single column table. Right?

Comment: i dont think that it will return a table. now id should return a single value only.